# Shortcut that bring me back on the previous window

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have many screens and I use several windows. So is there a shortcut that allows me to come back to the previous window?

Suppose I am using the Terminal. Next I switched to Chrome. Without using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, is there a shortcut which will bring me back on the terminal, sort of like an undo shortcut?

Comment: Alt-Shift-Tab, probably

Comment: @muru As you have experience with Python and C++, I would like to discuss with you without asking questions on askubuntu.com. Is there a place that we could discuss together? Of course, if you want.

Comment: What muru said, except you need to hit Atl+Tab first and hold alt, and then while holding shift hit tab again.

Comment: @Serg ah, it's  actually Alt-Ctrl-Tab then. That goes in the reverse direction directly, without having to press Alt-Tab first. Odd choice. J.Doe, sorry, I don't do general discussions much. If you have 20 rep anywhere on Stack Exchange, you can go to [chat], where you'll find a lot of people discussing a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut for directly switching windows in reverse order in Unity is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>. While already in the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> menu, you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to go in reverse order.

Comment: This might be broken in Ubuntu 20.10, then. Holding Shift makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You mean reverse order?
When you open chrome and terminal and files for examples.When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> you can only go from chrome to terminal but to go back to chrome you need to pass files.

At that time use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> which goes in reverser order.

Answer (score 0):

On machine with 20.04 I have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> set to "Switch applications" as a keyboard shortcut and pressing this quickly toggles between the last two applications I have been using.  If I hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> then I get the list to choose from.  For example I quite often send code from a terminal that opens a graphics device application and I quickly hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to get back to the terminal after looking at the graphics I've created.

Similarly I have <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> set to "Switch windows" so if I want to switch back to previous window within the same application (e.g. multiple terminal windows open) then I just press it quickly to toggle between them. If I want to do more than toggle between the last two used I hold down <kbd>Super</kbd> to get the list to browse through.